# slider zoom with selenium webDriver

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, selenium-webdriver, jquery-ui-slider

I have a problem with my slider when i drag and drop it with selenium webDriver
I have no zoom and the value before and after drag and drop is the same !!

below my code

my html code

```
<input type="range" class="zoom-range" id="myrange" name="rmouse"  min="0.25" max="2.00" step="0.01" value="1"/>
<div id="blocToZoom">
    ....
</div>
```

my selenium code:

```
WebElement slider = this.driver.findElement(By.id("myrange"));
System.out.println("The value of slider before dragDrop: "+slider.getAttribute("value"));
Actions move = new Actions(driver);
Action action = move.dragAndDropBy(slider, 30, 0).build();
action.perform();
System.out.println("The value of slider after dragDrop: "+slider.getAttribute("value"));
```

the result is the same

```
The value of slider before dragDrop: 1
The value of slider after dragDrop: 1
```

That mean the drag and drop dont work
so can someone give me solution of this problem.

i also try using this code but i have same problem

```
final WebElement slider = this.driver.findElement(By.id("myrange"));
System.out.println(slider.getAttribute("value"));
final Actions move = new Actions(this.driver);
final int Width = slider.getSize().getWidth();
final int Height = slider.getSize().getHeight();
final int MyX = (Width * 95) / 100;// spot to click is at 95% of the width
final int MyY = 1;// anywhere above Height/2 works
final Action actionDrag = move.dragAndDropBy(slider, MyX, MyY).build();
actionDrag.perform();
System.out.println(slider.getAttribute("value"));
```

PS: it works when i use Selenium 2.41.0 with firefox 30.0.1
but now i use Selenium 2.43.0 with firefox 32.0.1
maybe is that the problem !?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i don't think a successful drag should result in changing the value. I will suggest you to change dimension (30,0) to some bigger range. Currently value shows that you are trying to drag slider on X axis,not Y axis. Plez check this as well which Axis you wish to change

Comment: I tested different combinations rather by changing the y-axis and also by changing the x-axis, i have alse change the value by putting large or very small and it does not work I either have the same value of slider before and after dragDrop or i have this error: Given coordinates are outside the document.